# Error: ‘fmedian’ at (1) is not a variable

Tags: fortran

I want to see how this function works.I have tried to write small f77 code

```
      program pic

      implicit none
      integer c,a
      integer b(5)
      external fmedian
      c=5
      b=(/9,2,7,1,6/)  
      fmedian(a,b,c)

      end


      real function fmedian(xmed,x,n)
      double precision sum
      integer i,n,xmed
      dimension x(n)
      sum=0.d0
      do 10 i=1,n
        sum=sum+(x(i)-xmed)/abs(x(i)-xmed)
  10    continue
      fmedian=sum
      return
      end
```

What should I change in my pic code

When I try to compile Alexander`s code I got

```
       print *, fmedian(a,b,c)
                         1
Warning: Type mismatch in argument ‘x’ at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to REAL(4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fmedian` is a function, i.e. it returns something. However, you do not assign the return value anywhere.

You could, e.g., print the result of `fmedian` to the screen:

```
      print *, fmedian(a,b,c)
```

Additionally, you need to declare the return value of `fmedian`

```
      real fmedian
```

---

Your program would then look like:

```
      program pic

      implicit none
      integer c,a
      integer b(5)
      real fmedian
      external fmedian
      c=5
      b=(/9,2,7,1,6/)  
      print *, fmedian(a,b,c)

      end


      real function fmedian(xmed,x,n)
      double precision sum
      integer i,n,xmed
      dimension x(n)
      sum=0.d0
      do 10 i=1,n
        sum=sum+(x(i)-xmed)/abs(x(i)-xmed)
  10    continue
      fmedian=sum
      return
      end
```

Comment: The mismatch is still there between the caller integer array and the callee implicit real. Declaring x as integer array would fix it